# Do I need a pointer to a pointer here?

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-management, pointer-to-pointer

I have the following code:

```
char* get_line(char *buffer, char *line, char *partialLine) {

  int i = 0;
  while (buffer[i] != '\n' && buffer[i] != '\0') i++;

  if (buffer[i] == '\n') {

    line = malloc(sizeof(char) * (i+2));
    memcpy(line,buffer,i+1);
    line[i+1] = '\0';

    char *temp = append(partialLine,line);
    if (partialLine) {
      free(partialLine);
      partialLine = NULL;
    }
    free(line);
    line = temp;
    buffer = pop_buffer(buffer,i+1);

    return buffer;
  }
}
```

I want the function to fill in "line", so that when I return I have the value of temp in "line". At the moment, when debugging I see line gets the right value after the `line = temp` instruction. I want this to be kept after the return.

I think I need to pass a pointer to a pointer making the function prototype `char* get_line(char *buf, char **line, char *partialLine);`, but I'm only just getting to grips with regular pointers. What is the best way to solve this type of problem? Am I on the right tracks?

Comment: Please don't use the title to tag questions, removed the `[C]` from your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already give the better part of the answer. Just one nitpick:

> At the moment, when debugging I see line gets the right value after the `line = temp` instruction. I want this to be kept after the return.

That's **impossible**. C function calls pass arguments **by value**, so the `line` inside the function is a different variable than that outside and doesn't exist any more once the function exits. That's **why** you need to pass a pointer to a pointer here.

The bit of information you seem to be missing: A pointer isn't that much different from a normal variable, it stores a value. The only difference is that the value stored is the address of some other variable. Of course, you can handle a pointer to a pointer just the same way as a pointer to anything, and you can dereference twice. In your case, the simplest way would be to just change the parameter type and then replace every `line` by `*line` (which would access the pointer `line` points to).

Comment: I tried this and couldn't get it to work for some reason, I also tried changing the first 2 lines to this: `char* get_line(char *buf, char **line_p, char *partialLine) { char *line = *line_p;` , why doesn't that work?

Comment: Did you pass `&somebuffer` (where `somebuffer` is `char *`) as `line_p`? Did you `free (*line)`? (where was `*line` pointing?)

Comment: initially yes, but now I've done this:
`char **line = malloc(sizeof(char*));
  *line = NULL;`

Which I still can't get to work. When I check *line after return it has 0x0

Comment: This would make sense for empty input.

Comment: @toastedDeli you just have to pass a pointer *to a pointer declared in your calling code*, e.g. you have `char *line;` then you pass `&line`

Comment: @FelixPalmen I also tried that. I have no idea why it won't work.

Comment: @toastedDeli it works exactly that way, check the rest of your code. Take care about precedence in your function, `[]` is evaluated before `*`, so you might need parantheses.

Comment: @FelixPalmen got it, I forgot to change a variable somewhere else. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> I think I need to pass a pointer to a pointer

Yes you need a douple pointer, so that the value of the pointer (where the pointer points to) persists after the function terminates.

If you don't do that, you will have a memory leak, since the memory allocated to `line`, will not be referencable.